# Is this JSON element a compressed string? If yes, how can I decompress it?

Tags: javascript, json, inspectlet

I'm currently trying to work out how inspectlet, a user-session recording tool, is working from that [Demo](http://www.inspectlet.com/hello/capturedemo). Shortly, what it does is tracking every user action and make it possible to replay that session.

For that, the script is sending a (what I suppose) compressed string of the HTML markup via websocket to a server to show it in the replay. [Original code on pastebin no longer available]

I don't speak Japanese/Chinese but due to the fact that the company is based in Paolo Alto, I don't think that the string is actually Japanese or Chinese.

I hope some of you have some other ideas how I find out, what type of compression is used, and how I can decompress this string back to it's original content?

If it's a compressed string at all.

Comment: It could be some kind of binary format (probably for compression). Binary could be anything. See if you can find in the JS code where this string is produced.

Comment: Obviously this is the code for compressing/obfuscating the string: http://pastebin.com/naispzKU

But i really have no idea what's happening there... I guess I'll just try to replace their js-file with mine and do some debugging, to see what they're doing.